# Can SSMS use Azure Keyvault

Tags: ssms, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to get SQL Server Management studio to use Azure Keyvault to get the connection parameters (server and credentials)?

I've created a key vault, added username and password secrets, now I'd like SSMS to go and get those values so the user never knows them.

Answer (score 0):

I fear the short answer is no but there might be a better way of doing this than using a KeyVault.

I think the solution would be to add the user to the database as an Azure Active Directory user. There are instructions here [Add Azure Active Directory User to Azure SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044760/add-azure-active-directory-user-to-azure-sql-database)

- Go to the SQL server, select Active Directory Admin in the Settings
  section
- Click Set Admin and choose a user (I'm assuming you if you're setting
  all of this up)
- Click Save. I forgot this bit first time round.
- Now you can sign in to the database with Azure Active Directory -
  Password or Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA
- Right click on System Databases/master and create a new query
- Run `CREATE USER [a.name@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;`

And the user will be added to the database. I'm assuming that you'll still need to set permissions and the like but I think this would give you a simpler solution with more control over what people can do.

Your users might find Azure Data Studio even easier.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

This has an Azure section where you can log in with your Azure credentials. Once signed in you can at least discover resources on your Azure subscription and if your account has been granted access as above it's then possible to run queries without any further authentication.