# Connection to Azure SQL via Active Directory-Integrated

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have ADFS enabled in my domain and I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL database from SSMS  via Azure Active Directory-Integrated but I am getting the below error :

```
Failed to parse XML blob.
Reason: XML document must have a top level element.
Line: 0, Position: 0
Text: (null) (System.Data)
```

So is anyone familiar with this error? And what should I do to resolve it ?

I tried upgrading the version of SSMS to the latest one but still the same issue persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to parse XML blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533420/failed-to-parse-xml-blob)

Comment: You could try the solution in Martin's comment. It seams that every one may have different experience to resolve the issue. Microsoft also suggest ask Azure support for more assists: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/70396c1e-cf83-438c-9d63-6c870bac45f7/unable-connect-to-azure-sql-with-active-directory-integrated

Comment: Hi Nandan, hope you are doing well. Did you get any progresses?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solution in Martin's comment. Ohter people also shared how they resolve the issue : [Failed to parse XML blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533420/failed-to-parse-xml-blob)

I searched a lot but didn't find a exactly solution for this issue. Everyone may has different environment which cause the problem.

Some Microsoft engineers suggest us ask [Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get more assists:

- Please file an Azure Support ticket when this occurs and have the
  ticket assigned to the ADAL Team. If you do not have an Azure Support
  plan, a one-time ticket can be activated to capture this specific
  issue. Please reach out to AzCommunity at microsoft.com with your
  subscription GUID and this forum post.

Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/70396c1e-cf83-438c-9d63-6c870bac45f7/unable-connect-to-azure-sql-with-active-directory-integrated

These are all things we could get, hope it's helpful.